Как использовать удалённую отладку для Java в VS Code?
Я решил написать кроссплатформенное приложение на Java. Понятно, что чтобы убедиться в его  жизнеспособности необходимо проверить, как оно работает на Windows, Linux и MacOS. У меня Windows, так что с первым пунктом проблем не возникает. Для других ОС я решил использовать VirtualBox. Настроил машину, долго копался в настройках сети, и наконец...
...отладка заработала! Только ни посмотреть на вывод приложения в терминале VS Code, ни исправить код, ни даже остановить исполнение приложения я не могу.
Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы я мог отлаживать приложение на виртуальной машине также, как это делается в IDE? Чтобы не пришлось после каждого изменения заново экспортировать и запихивать в гостевую ОС новый jar-файл, чтобы можно было наблюдать за ходом выполнения и т. д.

Только что, наконец, разобрался. Оказывается, существует SSH - протокол, позволяющий работать с удалёнными ресурсами. Достаточно установить соответствующее расширение для VS Code.
